# Multipart form data: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

Spring MVC multipart file upload using ajax. Im using spring security so i have added csrf token also. I am getting following error:  `org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported`

**Input Form jsp:**

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="55" />
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="photo" name="photo" aria- 
    describedby="photoAddon">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="sign" name="sign" aria- 
    describedby="signAddon">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
    onclick="profWrapper.uploadPhotoSign()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**Ajax code:**

```
uploadPhotoSign : function() {
            event.preventDefault();
             // Get form
            var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

            // Create an FormData object 
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "uploadPhotoSign",
                data: formData,
                processData: false, // prevent jQuery form transforming the data into a query string
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
                succecc: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping("uploadPhotoSign")
    public ResponseEntity<String> savePhotoSign(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam MultipartFile photo,
            @RequestParam MultipartFile sign, 
            @RequestParam("id") int id){
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add csrf header in your ajax call
headers:{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': value}

check multipart project [here](http://github.com/ravenloup)
But that's sample project only

Answer (score 0):

Even though there was csrf hidden input field in the form, Adding csrf token in **request header** worked for me as below:

**input field:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" id="csrfTkn" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

**Ajax code:**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "uploadPhotoSign",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('#csrfTkn').val()},
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
   });
```